# delete all files from a path and keep only .parquet files using python

Tags: python, filesystems

I have a path mydir where i have file1,file2, .. file100 each folder have .crc,.bak etc, files i want to remove all files and keep only .parquet files and name the .parquet files with folder name
for eg., file1 folder have .crc,.bak files after removing we end up with .parquet i need to name this as file1.parquet.

I tried to remove one folder but couldnot do it for all folders uisng python

can someone help me how to solve this

```
mydir='c/users/name/files'
for f in os.listdir(mydir):
    if f.endswith(".parquet"):
        continue
    os.remove(os.path.join(mydir, f))
```

Comment: If you don't need to use Python, it could be better to do this using terminal commands. Otherwise, I think the [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module may be your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Following Miguel's comment, you can use `glob` like this:

```py
import glob
import os

mydir = "./"
dir_to_remove = []
for src_file in glob.glob(mydir + '**/.parquet', recursive=True):
    dir_, file_ = src_file.rsplit('/', 1)
    dir_to_remove.append(dir_)
    dst_file = dir_ + file_
    os.rename(src_file, dst_file)

for dir_ in dir_to_remove:
    os.rmdir(dir_)
```